# TFS 2018 build fails: cannot open include file 'afxres.h'

Tags: c++, tfs, tfsbuild

We are testing a new new TFS 2018 SP1 server.

I was previously building a solution (4.5) which contains two unmanaged C++ projects originally written against the 2012 toolset.

Building that solution as-is on the new server worked fine.  However, we have decided to retarget to 4.7.1 for our next release.

After making all the changes in the projects including targeting the 4.7.1 framework and the 2017 toolset (141), these projects fail to build with the error in the title.

I know this has to do with the C++ MFC/ATL redist.

The build server does not have VS 2017 installed and I do not want to install it unless absolutely necessary.

I did install the VS 2017 C++ redists x86 and x64 but it did not correct this.

Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: It does not have to do with MFC/ATL redist at all (redists are necessary for end users). It has to do with missing MFC SDK (which is an optional component under the Desktop development with C++ workload in the Visual Studio).

Comment: @VTT Sorry... I misspoke.  You're right, it's the SDK, not the redist.  My question still stands though.  Is there a way to fix this without installing VS itself?

Comment: @Sam Can you successfully build the project locally?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Yes, I can.  But I have VS2017 installed.  As noted above, I'm certain this is related to having the MFC/ATL support option installed with VS.  As far as I know, that option doesn't exist on TFS 2018 install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to at least install [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) on your build server.

> **Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017**
>
> These Build Tools allow you to build native and managed MSBuild-based
>   applications without requiring the Visual Studio IDE. There are
>   options to install the Visual C++ compilers and libraries, MFC, ATL,
>   and C++/CLI support, and .NET and .NET Core support.

If that still not work, I'm afraid that you have to install the VS 2017 on the build server. (Note that do not miss the feature `Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++` .)

---

UPDATE:

Please double check if you missed the **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools** workload on the build server. See [Visual C++ build tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools#visual-c-build-tools) for details.

If missed , just try using below command to install it:

```
vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools
```

Comment: Yeah, I installed the build tools when I first set up the server.  I don't want to install VS because it's like 50GB and that seems like a waste for this one tiny issue.

Comment: @Sam Have you installed all the Components included by the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools`? ([Visual C++ build tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools#visual-c-build-tools)).  See the updated answer.

Comment: I double-checked and that component wasn't installed.  This has solved my issue.  Thanks.